# A' union B' equals B'?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

what can I say about set A and B if

A'U B' = B'

the original question is why (A intersect B)' = B'

what I did was I used the dem's law

sol: (A intersect B)' = A'U B' 
     and now I left with A'U B'= B'
     I drew diagrams for both of them but I don't know how to explain.

Thanks! :) Ps. I hope my venn diagrams are right tho.

Comment: There seems to be context missing, e.g. do you know anything more about $A$ and $B$?

Comment: no I don't... the question is only asking what can I say about the sets of A and B if (A intersect B)' = B'

Comment: And there you have context: "If $(A\cap B)'=B'$, then...", this is important to the question because you can **assume** that this equality holds. The question is not asking "Why $(A\cap B)'=B'$", it is asking for something else. So please edit your post to correctly address the/your question.

Comment: What does ' in A' mean?

Comment: @fleablood complementation

Comment: Please write the *full* question. A' U B' *doesn't* equal B' in general.  But if there is a stated relationship between A and B (for example if B $\subset A) then *sometimes* A' U B' does equal B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:
$$
A' \cup B' = B'
$$
For any sets $X, Y$, it's always true that $X \subseteq X \cup Y$, so if $X \cup Y = Y$ then $X \subseteq Y$: $X$ is a subset of $Y$.

In your example, both $X$ and $Y$ are the complements $A', B'$. Thus:
$$
A' \subseteq B'
$$
But that is the same thing as:
$$
B \subseteq A
$$

#### Another approach

The original question is:
$$
(A \cap B)' = B'
$$
One way, shown above, is to use De Morgan's law. Another way is to take complements of both sides (*get rid* of the complements, simplify) and obtain:
$$
A \cap B = B
$$
For any sets $A, B$, it's always true that $A \cap B \subseteq A$. So if $A \cap B = B$, then again we've proved that $B \subseteq A$.

Example: $B = \{0, 1\} \subseteq A = \{0, 1, 2\}$ as subsets of $\{0, 1, \dots, 9\}$.  The complements are $A' = \{3, 4, \dots, 9\}$, $B' = \{2, 3, 4, \dots, 9\}$. Note that $A' \subseteq B'$, so of course $A\ \cup B' = B'$.

Comment: but my question is asking what can I say about set A and B if A′∪B′ =B′

Comment: I've shown you in two ways that you can say quite a lot: $A \supseteq B$.

Comment: thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Oh good, glad you see it now :) Don't neglect to vote someone's answer "correct".

Comment: I have been finding it since you posted!!! but where is it ??

Comment: By "it" I meant "why $A \supseteq B$" ... I'm not sure that's what you just meant.

Comment: no I meant how do I vote if the answer is correct?

Comment: Seems you figured that out too ;/

Answer (score 0):

$A' \cup B' = B'$ means $A'$ adds nothing to $B'$, that is every element of $A'$ belongs also to $B'$. And that in turn is an inclusion relation: $A'$ is a subset of $B'$: $A' \subseteq B'$.